# VisualStudio 2010 - How do you display only YEAR in a chart?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

This is the code I used in my dataset. The result is as shown in the image.
The plan is to display the YEAR without month, day or time. Is this feasible?

```
SELECT  t.Name AS Territoryname,
        p.LastName AS SalesPerson,
        c.CardType AS PayType,
       s.OrderDate,
       s.TotalDue
FROM    Sales s
JOIN    Person p 
ON      s.SalesPersonID=p.BusinessEntityID 
JOIN    CreditCard c 
ON      c.CreditCardID=s.CreditCardID
JOIN    Territoryt 
ON      t.TerritoryID=s.TerritoryID
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this. The easiest, is to calculate a year value directly in your dataset, and then use this field in your chart. This is a simple matter of adding the following code to the `select` part of your dataset:

```
select
    ...
    s.OrderDate,
    YEAR(s.OrderDate) AS [OrderYear],    -- This is the new field
    s.TotalDue
from
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can create an expression that does the same thing, either as a calculated field in your dataset, or directly in the chart as the category field.

Comment: I ran the code using "YEAR (s.OrderDate) AS [OrderYear]" inside the expression window in visualStudios. However I go an error code that tha DadaSet name is invalid

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add a comma after the [OrderYear] alias. Sorry. Try add the comma as shown in my code.

Comment: THank YOu Dan, I wrote the code (with YEAR) in SQL, then reinserted it into VisualStudio. It worked fine